# Python Web Scrape using Beautiful Soup - Return all product details from a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Apologies for the very newbie question but I am just beginning my Python journey, and starting to learn about webscraping.

I have written some code to scrape a fashion website and return bits of product information. What i'd really like to do instead is scrape the main category page and pull off all product names and prices. I figure that I will need to use a FOR loop, and I have tried various iterations that I have found looking at this site but I can't seem to get it to work.

I want to pull the product name and price for all items on the page so I can then export. The code below works fine for returning the first item on the page, but Im not sure how to add a loop to get the rest.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.riverisland.com/c/men/seasonal-offers?icid=mhp/winter-treats/m/seasonal-offers/cat'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

data_item = []
  for item in name_box, price_box:
  data_item.append()

  name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'product__title ui-body-text'})
  price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'product-price__headline-product-price__headline--sale'})

  name = name_box.text.strip()
  price = price_box.text.strip()
```

Comment: Would you update the question about what info you want to crawl and what type of error occuring?

Comment: Apologies, have tried to be a bit more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. You did the minor mistake. What you trying to crawl is single product name through `find`. Instead you have to try `find_all` for all the product.

The other thing is in your `price` crawl data, actually two `class` which should be combine by `.` instead of `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all the products in the page. `find` only gets you the first product. You need to use [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to get all the products in the page. Then you can loop through it and print them.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.riverisland.com/c/men/seasonal-offers?icid=mhp/winter-treats/m/seasonal-offers/cat'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product__title ui-body-text'})
price_box = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-price__headline product-price__headline--sale'})

for product in zip(name_box,price_box):
    name,price=product
    name_proper=name.text.strip()
    price_proper=price.text.strip()
    print(name_proper,'-',price_proper)
```

Output

```
Bellfield navy three-in-one mac coat - £50.00
Black rib muscle fit short sleeve T-shirt - £12.00
Criminal Damage black colour block zip jacket - £50.00
Jack & Jones Premium green puffer gilet - £30.00
Jack & Jones red faux fur bomber jacket - £50.00
Jack & Jones black parka jacket - £70.00
Light grey ribbed muscle fit T-shirt - £12.00
Navy satin velour panel slim fit T-shirt - £12.00
Pepe Jeans light blue denim jacket - £90.00
Navy slim fit tape crew neck T-shirt - £12.00
Superdry green camo parka jacket - £90.00
Superdry green double zip Fuji padded jacket - £60.00
Superdry green hooded parka jacket - £80.00
Superdry navy hooded quilted jacket - £80.00
Superdry navy triple zip funnel neck jacket - £60.00
Superdry red zip funnel neck puffer jacket - £60.00
Superdry yellow lightweight hooded jacket - £70.00
Superdry black camo funnel neck coat - £70.00
Superdry black double zip Fuji padded jacket - £60.00
Superdry black funnel neck puffer jacket - £60.00
Superdry blue lightweight hooded jacket - £70.00
Superdry green army jacket - £60.00
Only & Sons black hooded puffer jacket - £40.00
Pepe Jeans dark blue denim jacket - £90.00
Red waffle slim fit short sleeve T-shirt - £12.00
Selected Homme black stripe long sleeve top - £50.00
White waffle slim fit short sleeve T-shirt - £12.00
Big and Tall R96 burgundy muscle fit T-shirt - £12.00
Black Dean straight leg jeans - £20.00
Black R96 muscle fit long sleeve T-shirt - £12.00
Black R96 pique muscle fit long sleeve shirt - £15.00
Black ribbed crew neck long sleeve top - £12.00
Black velour R96 slim fit piped joggers - £20.00
Blue Dylan slim fit distressed jeans - £25.00
Dark blue straight leg jeans - £20.00
Dark blue straight leg jeans - £20.00
Dark blue straight leg manhattan jeans - £20.00
Dark blue ripped super skinny jeans - £25.00
Dark blue Dean straight leg jeans - £20.00
Dark blue Dylan slim fit jeans - £25.00
Dark grey R96 muscle fit grandad shirt - £15.00
Burgundy slim fit colour block sleeve hoodie - £20.00
Burgundy R96 muscle fit grandad shirt - £15.00
Dark red R95 muscle fit raglan T-shirt - £12.00
Dark red R96 muscle fit long sleeve T-shirt - £12.00
Dark red wasp embroidered Oxford shirt - £15.00
Green poplin muscle fit long sleeve shirt - £15.00
Grey check button down long sleeve shirt - £20.00
Light blue long sleeve flannel shirt - £20.00
R96 black velour slim fit hoodie - £20.00
Pink R96 muscle fit button-down shirt - £15.00
White ribbed crew neck long sleeve top - £12.00
Khaki slim fit tape sleeve hoodie - £20.00
Stone pique muscle fit long sleeve shirt - £15.00
Black lace up chukka boot - £25.00
Black 'Prolific' padded puffer coat - £45.00
Black muscle fit rib crew neck jumper - £20.00
Black hooded borg lined jacket - £45.00
Black longline faux fur hooded parka jacket - £45.00
Black zip front funnel neck puffer jacket - £25.00
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about find_all , this makes total sense!

Comment: @ScottCee You can find more about that in the link (which is the official documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to figure out a solution for you but for now try to use the

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'your attributes'}
```

function